# Site blocked by content filter

Tags: wordpress, traffic, content, filtering

I run a large and high trafficked WordPress powered platform. One of my editors informed me that our site is blocked at his workspace as a "games site". They use WebCat to filter the traffic.

The issue here is that our platform is not a gaming site, although it does have a `games` category that covers news. And that is a very minor part of the site.

My question is, what can I do to unblock the site? How does WebCat work? Do they use a universal database to filter the traffic (meaning that the site is blocked on all workspace with WebCat) etc. Obviously they need to improve their filtering algorithm.

Comment: Filtering proxies filter based on the contents of the site, it could be one page or hundred they don't care... They block sites, not pages.

Comment: most proxies not all.

Comment: Contact WebCat and tell them to fix their shoddy software?

Comment: Do they have an official website and are their content filter database universal (please read my question)?

Comment: It also doesn't necessarily mean your site is a 'games' site. 'Games site' may just be the name of their firewall rule.

I have a ton of sites where I work that are blocked as 'Facebook' sites. not because they have anything to do with Facebook, but that was just the name of the rule my the company started with and never renamed.

Comment: @ChristineCooper A Google search of WebCat Filter brings up http://www.motor.com/page.asp?page_ID=129 so yes they have a website. As DisgruntledGoat suggested, contact them if you want your site to not be filtered by their software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebCat system you refer to I believe is owned and operated as a hosted service by Cyberoam/Sophos.

1. Check the current categorization for your website URL by entering it into their [Web Categorization URL Lookup](http://www.cyberoamsecuritycenter.com/cyberoamsupport/webpages/webcat/webcathome.jsp) form.
2. If you consider the resulting category to be inaccurate then they also then show you a web-based form into which you can suggest a more appropriate category by selecting one from a given drop-down list. You will have to supply an email address and may optionally add a comment to your suggested recategorization when you submit it.
3. WebCat staff will then manually review your suggestion and if they agree with you will update the category within a period of 24 hours (according to their website).

In case you come across this issue again with another web filtering solution, you should note that this process with any other provider would normally be almost identical to this, and the best place to start is on the solution provider's website.